# How write Head column in EsperIO with CSV?

Tags: esper, epl

How to write Head column via Data Flow?

I am using EsperIO with CSV, and I am writing Event properties in CSV. But there is no Head column. I want to write in a Head Column.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The first row in the csv can be the property names i.e. header row.

Comment: Yes, I know it. But I want to writing Event Properties's name to CSV via Data flow or EsperIO Adapter. Thx to read and answer.